# Open Graph URL/path for facebook games feed for getting posts from a certain game app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the PHP facebook's SDK API.

you know how certain games post on a facebook's user wall ? something like "John just reached level 3!" along with a link that says something like "click here to free coins!" and if his facebook friends click that link they get free coins (game bonus)
the link always starts with "apps.facebook.com"

I'm trying to fetch these messages/posts/links from the game "CityVille" (app id = 291549705119)
and can't find were I get them.
already looked into:

```
/me/feed/
/me/links/
/me/statuses/
```

what is the right path for it ?

the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is a great help when you know where to find what you want but I don't know where (path in the graph) these posts are suppose to appear.